# Which tag I am at GIT

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

I am new to GIT. Last week I checked out my code to a tag. I forgot the tag name and apparently have some issue with code, so I want to know which tag I checked out from. How can I find that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `git describe` command to find the "closest" tag associated with your current commit:

```
git describe --tags
```

For example, in a sample repository this gives me:

```
testtag-2-g25a38be
```

This means I am at commit `g25a38be`, which is two commits beyond the tag `testtag`.